# Restore a database from multiple .bak files SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, database-restore

Third party is sending us split backups that we need to restore everyday into single database. Is there a way to automate this which is low maintenance?

Preference is to do this writing either T-SQL or a SQL Server job:

- AdventureWorks07182018.back0
- AdventureWorks07182018.back1
- AdventureWorks07182018.back2
- AdventureWorks07182018.back3

Comment: Your question literally looks like you might have read this [solution](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-create-sql-server-database-split-backup-files/).

Comment: I actually did, but got confused a bit since this is something I am doing for the first time. Scsimon's answer seems to be pointing me to a right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment, but this is usually done in an SQL Agent Job.

Split backups means 1 of (at least) 4 things which you'll need to get clarification from the vendor, if you don't already know. I excluded partial backups:

1. The vendor is sending all of the backups listed above in one day, meaning it's a base and 3 differentials or log backups (possible)
2. The vendor is only sending differential backups since they originally sent you the base (unlikely)
3. The vendor is backing up filegroups or files on different days (maybe a VLDB) and sending to you as they happen (unlikely scenario)
4. The vendor is sending you daily full backups, in which the last one you got is the most recent (most likely)

Excluding file and filegroup restores, you will:

1. Restore the full backup
2. Restore the *last* differential backup, if applicable
3. Restore any log backups that happened after the *last* differential backup, or since the last full backup if differentials aren't happening

You could also choose any differential in step 2, and then all log backups since that differential if it exists. Naturally, if they are *only* sending you full backups, then you simply need to restore the full backup only.

Something along these lines... which will vary based on your environment (AlwaysOn, setting to read only, setting to STANDBY, etc...)

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] FROM  DISK ='\\UNC\AdventureWorks.back0'
WITH
--what ever options... but likely a file move
MOVE 'data_file_1' TO 'E:\somefolder\data.mdf',
MOVE 'db_log' TO 'E:\somefolder\log.ldf',
REPLACE, --overwrites the database
RECOVERY --sets the DB to READ/WRITE. Use NORECOVERY if you need to restore logs / differentials
GO

--if using logs...
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks
   FROM '\\UNC\AdventureWorks.back01' --assuming this is a log
   WITH FILE = 1,  --this is the first log
   WITH NORECOVERY;  --keep in norecovery to restore other logs...
GO
```

etc...

Comment: Vendor is actually sending us one file .Lts.bak, which requires executing LiteSpeed extractor using command prompt.  Once successful, I am left with four files.  My concern is, how do I know which order to restore them in and what if one day I get only three files from extract and next day I get 5.  I am guessing best approach is to restore them one by one?  I'll reach out to vendor for clarification!  Appreciate your help!  I'll make this question as answered.

Comment: In that case, you can ask them but also just restore the header to see what each file contains. You can [**read up on that here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)