# Script to restore SQL Server database with multiple BAK files

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, database-restore

I am trying to come up with a script to dynamically do 'Restore Database' in SQL Server 2019 with multiple BAK files that are located in one folder on a daily basis.

I will do the manual full backup first, and this task will be scheduled to run after on a daily basis.

The plan is go thru each BAK files (located in the same folder) sequentially (for example here: 04 --> 12).

There will be another Python script which will wipe out old files, so I am only focusing on execution of Restore database with BAK files that are located in this folder.

What should be the best approach?

I have attached a screenshot that has all BAK files.

[image]

I have some T-SQL code here (that I copied from [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410723/restore-a-database-from-multiple-bak-files-sql-server-2012)), but I am not sure how to loop over each BAK file sequentially.

And I am not sure whether I have to deal with mdf and ldf files as listed here.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Test] FROM  DISK ='\\Folder\LOG...04.bak'
WITH
--what ever options... but likely a file move
MOVE 'data_file_1' TO 'E:\somefolder\data.mdf',
MOVE 'db_log' TO 'E:\somefolder\log.ldf',
REPLACE, --overwrites the database
RECOVERY --sets the DB to READ/WRITE. Use NORECOVERY if you need to restore 
logs / differentials
GO

RESTORE LOG Test
   FROM '\\Folder\Log...04.bak' --assuming this is a log
   WITH FILE = 1,  --this is the first log
   WITH NORECOVERY;  --keep in norecovery to restore other logs...
GO
```

Comment: Nope, very few do "best" answers because that depends on too many variables. But this seems to be highly similar goal to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275211/convert-multiple-files-using-command-line-with-python). You loop over the files that match a pattern in a directory and restore them. Seems you have an assumption about the type of backup each file represents.

Comment: @vonPryz It is only for one database. They are all transaction logs.

Comment: @SMor, What are variables in this case? Is it better doing it in Python? I thought T-SQL might do.

Comment: Please don't save transaction logs as .bak files. It is customary to use .bak for full backup, .dif for differential and .trn for logs. That way it is trivial to tell files apart.

Comment: @vonPryz I think the issue for me was I did not know the difference between bak, trn and dif file formats until you pointed out.  Thanks for awakening. Please check bottom URL, and let me know if this is a good approach or not.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1584/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script-from-backup-files-in-a-directory/
Since I only have BAK format, I will only use part of the script.